# How do I run a multiarch Docker image for a foreign architecture?

Tags: python, docker, qemu

With the new multiarch Docker infrastructure, you can run, say, `python:3.6` and it will automatically choose the right image you based on the host architecture. Now, how can I override this and run a variant of the image built for another architecture, assuming that I have the appropriate qemu and binfmt support in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is consistent across all images, but for [official images](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images) all it takes is prefixing an image name with the architecture:

```
docker run s390x/python:3.7-alpine3.8 python --version
docker run arm64v8/alpine uname -a
```

You can check the above repo for supported architectures for each release.